# JS How to save the result of a for loop as an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
const cars = ['BMW', 'Volvo', 'Saab', 'Ford', 'Fiat', 'Audi'];
const arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  const i = 'hi';
  console.log(i);
}
```

the result of this code would be:

```
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
```

how can I save this result to a variable as an array?
The returned value should be: `['hi','hi','hi','hi','hi','hi']`

Comment: Add `arr.push(i)` to the loop.

Comment: Why are you declaring `i` inside the loop with the same name as the loop counter? What if you needed the value of the loop counter inside the loop?

Comment: `(new Array(cars.length)).fill('hi')`

Answer (score 1):

```
const cars = ['BMW', 'Volvo', 'Saab', 'Ford', 'Fiat', 'Audi'];
const arr = [];
const x = 'hi';

for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  arr.push(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can make use of is `map` operator

```
const cars = ['BMW', 'Volvo', 'Saab', 'Ford', 'Fiat', 'Audi'];
const arr = cars.map(car => 'hi');
```

Comment: Also `[...cars].fill('hi')`

Answer (score 0):

Another option using [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
const cars = ['BMW', 'Volvo', 'Saab', 'Ford', 'Fiat', 'Audi'];
const arr = Array.from(cars, _ => "hi");
```

```js
const cars = ['BMW', 'Volvo', 'Saab', 'Ford', 'Fiat', 'Audi'];
const arr = Array.from(cars, _ => "hi");
console.log(arr);
```